# Super thinks it is not the first constructor in a statement

Tags: java, inheritance, extend, superclass, super

I can't seeem to get this code to work. I have several different classes listed out, and they extend each other. The code for the box super, however, tends to not think it is the first constructor.

```
 public class Rectangle3
 {
// instance variables 
private int length;
private int width;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class rectangle
 */
public void Rectangle(int l, int w)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    length = l;
    width = w;
}

// return the height
public int getLength()
{
    return length;
}
public int getWidth()
{
    return width;
}
```

}

Then the next one

```
 public class Box3 extends Rectangle3
{
// instance variables 
private int height;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class box
 */
public void Box(int l, int w, int h)
{
    // call superclass
    super (l, w);
    // initialise instance variables
    height = h;
}

// return the height
public int getHeight()
{
    return height;
}
```

}

then the cube...

```
public class Cube3 extends Box3
{
   //instance variable
private int depth;

/**
 * Cube constructor class
 */   
    public void Cube(int l, int w, int h, int d)
   {
   //super call
   super(l, w, h);
   //initialization of instance variable
   depth = d;
}

//return call to depth
public int getDepth()
{
    return depth;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't have constructors defined. The **method** `public void Box(int l, int w, int h)` is not a constructor for a `Box3` class, and therefor use of `super(..)` is invalid. The same goes for the methods `public void Cube(int l, int w, int h, int d)` and `public void Rectangle(int l, int w)`

Instead you need to define a constructor in `Box3`:

```
public Box3(int l, int w, int h) {
    // call superclass
    super (l, w);
    // initialise instance variables
    height = h;
}
```

Notice the lack of `void` and the fact its name is identical to the class name.

Note that the above constructor will not work, because `Rectangle3` doesn't have this constructor. So for `Rectangle3` you need to use:

```
public Rectangle3(int l, int w) {
    // initialise instance variables
    length = l;
    width = w;
}
```

And the same goes for `Cube3`:

```
public Cube3(int l, int w, int h, int d) {
    //super call
    super(l, w, h);
    //initialization of instance variable
    depth = d;
}
```

See also the [Java Tutorial "Providing Constructors for Your Classes"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).

Comment: Figured it out. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @NoahWickham If an answer helped you, then please [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it by ticking the checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void Box(int l, int w, int h)
```

I'm sure your code works if you change that line to

```
public Box3(int l, int w, int h)
```

Comment: With the presence of `void` it is still not a constructor.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Right, just saw the missing `3` and didn't realize the `void`... updating my answer and +1 yours

Comment: Changed it and it works out great, thanks for the help!